# how to perform a bulk update with a list of objects linq c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of objects, for example

```
list<Employee> Employees = 
[
 {
   id:1,
   name: Luke,
   age: 5
 },
 {
   id:2,
   name: Elizabeth,
   age: 15
 },
]
```

How can I perfom a bulk update, should I use a foreach, or is there a way to perfom the update in a single line, the objets will have more properties and every property may change

Comment: By LINQ C#, do you mean Entity Framework? Out of the box, EF doesn't do that. However, there are plug-ins to do it. Example: https://entityframework.net/bulk-update

Comment: @Flydog57 that's right I mean the EF

Comment: Hi @darkknightlullaby, that question was answered a few years ago :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193369/bulk-update-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: Read all the answers in the linked duplicate - you probably want the one recommending the BulkExtensions library

Answer (score 0):

yes - foreach and single line:

```
Employees.ForEach(emp => emp.age++);
```

Comment: ok the list actually have the data that will update the database, the foreach is the correct way to update the records?

Comment: This will change the in-memory representation of your data. It doesn't handle the part of your question that became clear through the comments that you wish to update a database table.